# автоматическое добавление закрывающей скобки в IDE(любой) и ее целесообразность

Tags: печать, работа-с-текстом

Во многих IDE и редакторах при печати открывающей скобки автоматически печатается и закрывающая. Так вот у меня возник вопрос что делать после того как ввел выражение внутри скобок.Может я неправильно это использую?

Тянуться до кнопки "Направо"? (при этом могут быть несколько вложенных скобочных выражений, да еще и в кавычках) В этом случае придется отрывать взгляд от экрана. Что не так выгодно при слепой печати. Как на данный момент я и делаю, так как скобки уже стоят.

Comment: Ну наверное можно выключить вставку скобок, если не нравится, не?

Comment: В большинстве редакторов можно настроить поведение как у кнопок `down` `left` `right` `up` на горячие клавиши. Другое дело, что подобная настройка может быть не совсем очевидна.

Answer (score 0):

Во всех ide, что я использовал, в этой ситуации достаточно нажать на клавиатуре на тот же символ, который "мешает" курсору справа и курсор "перепрыгнет" через препятствие. Точно работает со всеми скобками и одинарными/двойным кавычками.

Comment: dima87g, тогда теряется весь смысл автоматически закрывающих скобок.